# Duplicates not getting ignored in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2016

I have a temp table that has two rows. 
Their Id is 999359143, 999365081

I have a table that doesn't have a primary key but has a unique index based off of the id and date.

This 999359143 already exists in the table. So when I use my query it still is trying to insert the row from the temp table into the normal table and it errors. This is the query below

```
INSERT INTO [XferTable]
           ([DataDate]
           ,[LoanNum]
          )

SELECT Distinct t1.[DataDate]
           ,t1.[LoanNum]               
FROM #AllXfers t1 WITH(HOLDLOCK) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT t2.LoanNum, t2.DataDate
                    FROM XferTable t2 WITH(HOLDLOCK) 
                   WHERE t2.LoanNum = t1.LoanNum AND t2.DataDate = t1.DataDate
)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please give an example of exact data in both tables that is causing this error.

Comment: ...and the exact error. The query you have written _should_ do what you're describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`MERGE`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/) statement, which acts [atomically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) so you shouldn't need to do your own locking (also, [isolation query hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver15) on temporary tables doesn't achieve anything).

```
MERGE XferTable AS SOURCE
USING #AllXfers AS TARGET
ON
    SOURCE.[DataDate] = TARGET.[DataDate]
    AND SOURCE.[LoanNum] = TARGET.[LoanNum]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET--record in SOURCE but not in TARGET
THEN INSERT
(
     [DataDate]
    ,[LoanNum]
)
VALUES
(
     SOURCE.[DataDate]
    ,TARGET.[LoanNum]
);
```

Your primary key violation is probably because you are using (Date, Loan#) as the uniqueness criteria and your primary key is probably only on Loan#.